# Group Members cant see list items with Read permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions, custom-permission-level

I'm new to share point and I have some permissions issues. I set Sharepoint Members group permissions to "Read" but all the list items disappear for a particular list. They are only visible with the "edit" permissions. On another list, I have them with "read" permissions and they can see the list items.

But to make things clear. I have 3 custom groups. In order for the users in "Engineers" to see items in a list, I have to have "everyone except external users" in the Sharepoint member group.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm using Sharepoint 365

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, I would check the permission of the group to the list by going to the list settings then *Permission to the list* and then *Check Permission* and provide the group name. The same way, you could check individual user's permission as well. Also, does the list has *Item Level* permission turned on?

Comment: I have checked both of those. and it still does not work. The "Engineers" group can only see the list if I put "CAD Schedule Members" with edit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Whether items in the list have their own unique permissions?

For the members group, you could remove restricted view permission, then have a test to see users whether can view items in the lists.

Comment: I have done that. "Engineers" group can see the list items only if I put "CAD Schedule Members" with edit permissions.

Comment: Have you check draft item security in the list versioning settings?